# "shader program is not linked" when running QT hello opengl

Tags: qt, opengl, shader

I have downloaded a QT OpenGL tutorial from http://releases.qt-project.org/learning/developerguides/qtopengltutorial/OpenGLTutorial.pdf and am trying to run the simplest example they have in there, which simply draws a triangle on top of a black background.

I managed to compile the example, but when I run it, I only get a black window and the console reports the following:

> Starting
>   /home/minas/Desktop/hello-opengl-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/hello-opengl...
>   QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( mvpMatrix ): shader program is not
>   linked  QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is
>   not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ): shader
>   program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ):
>   shader program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation(
>   vertex ): shader program is not linked 
>   QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( mvpMatrix ): shader program is not
>   linked  QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is
>   not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ): shader
>   program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ):
>   shader program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation(
>   vertex ): shader program is not linked 
>   QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( mvpMatrix ): shader program is not
>   linked  QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is
>   not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ): shader
>   program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ):
>   shader program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation(
>   vertex ): shader program is not linked 
>   QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( mvpMatrix ): shader program is not
>   linked  QGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is
>   not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ): shader
>   program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation( vertex ):
>   shader program is not linked  QGLShaderProgram::attributeLocation(
>   vertex ): shader program is not linked

The .pro file looks like this (the "unix:!mac" part is my addition, so it finds the OpenGL .so files).

```
QT += core gui opengl

TARGET = hello-opengl

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
           glwidget.cpp

HEADERS += glwidget.h

OTHER_FILES += fragmentShader.fsh\
               vertexShader.vsh

RESOURCES += resources.qrc

unix:!mac{
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath=/usr/lib64/nvidia-current
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += -L/usr/lib64/nvidia-current
}
```

The output of "glxinfo | grep -i opengl" is

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9800 GT/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 304.64
OpenGL shading language version string: (null)
OpenGL extensions:
```

and the part of the code that does the actual rendering is

```
void GlWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    QMatrix4x4 mMatrix;
    QMatrix4x4 vMatrix;

    // shaderProgram initialized in initializeGL()    
    shaderProgram.bind();

    // "mvpMatrix", "color" and "vertex" do exist in the shaders

    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);

    shaderProgram.setUniformValue("color", QColor(Qt::white));

    shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
    shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());

    shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");

    shaderProgram.release();
}
```

Also, as a side-question, why does the output of "glxinfo | grep -i opengl" contain the line

> OpenGL shading language version string: (null)

(kinda seems relevant to me... is it?)

---

### EDIT 1

The `shaderProgram` is declared in my subclass of `QGLWidget`, which I call `GLWidget` and initialized in `initializeGL` as such:

```
void GlWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::black));

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vertexShader.vsh");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragmentShader.fsh");
    shaderProgram.link();

    vertices << QVector3D(1, 0, -2) << QVector3D(0, 1, -2) << QVector3D(-1, 0, -2);
}
```

---

### EDIT 2

Here is my initializeGL() method:

```
void GlWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    qglClearColor(QColor(Qt::black));

    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Vertex, ":/vertexShader.vsh");
    shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceFile(QGLShader::Fragment, ":/fragmentShader.fsh");
    shaderProgram.link();

    vertices << QVector3D(1, 0, -2) << QVector3D(0, 1, -2) << QVector3D(-1, 0, -2);
}
```

and putting

```
qDebug() << shaderProgram.log();
exit(0);
```

immediately after the call to link() above does not produce any output.

Comment: "*shaderProgram was initialized in the class constructor*" Was it? The error is saying that the program wasn't properly created and linked.

Comment: Thanks for your response, let me edit my original post with some more info. 

Bear in mind that I am trying to run a tutorial example which comes with source code from the QT website, so it is supposed to work as it is.

Comment: shaderProgram.log() just returns a string containing the OpenGL shader compilation log. Try printing this information out to console with qDebug() << shaderProgram.log() and post the output if there is anything.

Comment: Nothing at all, the output is ""

Answer (score 1):

Was seeing this just now. Was strange because `link()` was returning true, yet it claimed the program was not linked?

Turned out I needed to move two `bindAttributeLocation()` statements to before my `link()` call. Apparently if you use `bindAttributeLocation()` on a program after it's linked, it will cause the program to no longer be linked.

Wrong:

```
    program.link();

    program.bindAttributeLocation("position", 0);
    program.bindAttributeLocation("texcoord", 1);
```

Right:

```
    program.bindAttributeLocation("position", 0);
    program.bindAttributeLocation("texcoord", 1);

    program.link();
```

Answer (score -1):

> // shaderProgram was initialized in the class constructor

If you compiled and linked shader source files in your class constructor then that is most likely the culprit. You should override the initializeGL member of QGLWidget and do the intialization for OpenGL objects there. You cannot do this any earlier as your OpenGL context has not been established, and thus you cannot create or manage any OpenGL objects.

Comment: Good guess but that's not it. The object is properly initialized in initializeGL(), let me post some more code in my original post. Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just realized that I had typed in the comment "initialized in the constructor" when I actually meant to say initializeGL

Comment: Could you try dumping the compile log after you link the program? (shaderProgram.log()) Also, call exit(0) after you dump the log so that the uniformLocation / attributeLocation errors don't print over the errors we want.

Comment: Did so and there is no output. I feel it has to do with the fact that glxinfo reports "OpenGL shading language version string: (null)" but I am not sure how to fix that...

Comment: OH, did you pass your QGLWidget subclass a QGLFormat object? If you didn't , QGLWidget might not set a version number, or may use a version utilizing the fixed function pipeline (ala no shaders). So, if you did not supply a format, try instantiating a QGLFormat object, call setVersion(major,minor), and pass the object to your GLWidget constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I found that problem too, I just used `FromSourceCode` instead from `FromSourceFile` like this:

```
shaderProgram.addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Fragment,  "uniform vec4 color;\n"
                                      "out vec4 fragColor;\n"
                                      "void main(void)\n"
                                      "{\n"
                                      "   fragColor = color;\n"
                                      "}");
```